# Can a BFS be implemented without a queue or stack?

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I was wondering how I could do this without using a queue or a hashTable but instead use a fixed array for the lookup table. This is my BFS algorithm for solving a 2x2 rubiks cube. What I want to do is store all the positions searched with its solution in a file so that if I was to give the program a scrambled cube it will search for that state of the cube and print out the solution for it.

```
static private void solve(Cube c) {
    Set<Cube> cubesFound = new HashSet<Cube>();
    cubesFound.add(c);

    Stack<Cube> s = new Stack<Cube>();
    s.push(c);

    Set<Stack<Cube>> initialPaths = new HashSet<Stack<Cube>>();
    initialPaths.add(s);

    solve(initialPaths, cubesFound);
}

static private void solve(Set<Stack<Cube>> livePaths, Set<Cube> cubesFoundSoFar) {
    System.out.println("livePaths size:" + livePaths.size());
    int numDupes = 0;

    Set<Stack<Cube>> newLivePaths = new HashSet<Stack<Cube>>();

    for(Stack<Cube> currentPath : livePaths) {

        Set<Cube> nextStates = currentPath.peek().getNextStates();

        for (Cube next : nextStates) {
            if (currentPath.size() > 1 && next.isSolved()) {
                currentPath.push(next);
                System.out.println("Path length:" + currentPath.size());
                System.out.println("Path:" + currentPath);
                System.exit(0);

            } else if (!cubesFoundSoFar.contains(next)) {
                Stack<Cube> newCurrentPath = new Stack<Cube>();
                newCurrentPath.addAll(currentPath);
                newCurrentPath.push(next);
                newLivePaths.add(newCurrentPath);
                cubesFoundSoFar.add(next);
            } else {
                numDupes += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Duplicates found " + numDupes + ".");
    solve(newLivePaths, cubesFoundSoFar);
}


private Cube() {
    cube = new int[][] {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 2, 2, 2, 2 },
        { 3, 3, 3, 3 },
        { 4, 4, 4, 4 },
        { 5, 5, 5, 5 }
    };
    cube = scanCube(cube);
    cube = print_cube(cube);
 //scanCube is just a method that takes input of the state of the cube in 2d array form
 //print_cube is a method formats the 2d array to look like a flat cube.
}

private Cube(Cube other) {
    cube = new int[other.cube.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < other.cube.length; i++) {
        cube[i] = Arrays.copyOf(other.cube[i], other.cube[i].length);
    }

}



private boolean isSolved() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cube.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 1; k < cube[i].length; k++) {
            if (cube[i][0] != cube[i][k]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {

     return other instanceof Cube && Arrays.deepEquals(((Cube) other).cube, cube);
}
```

Comment: Since BFS is for searching a tree structure, how are you going to remember all the branches yet to be searched if you don't have a *queue* for remembering them (note that *stack* is for DFS)? You can use a *fixed-size array* if you know the limit up front, but isn't that just a different implementation of a *stack*?

Comment: You can use an big-enough array (as you normally know the total state of the BFS) to mimic the queue if you insist...by using two pointers pointing to the index indicating the queue head and queue end. Update these pointers while doing BFS and stop the BFS when you meet satisfying state or head > queue.

Comment: I know the maximum amount of positions I need to have in the array. I I am not sure if its a different implementation of stack it could be. @Andreas

Comment: @uswer1242 Sorry, I meant *queue*. You would just be using the array as a queue, similar to an `ArrayDeque`, so why not just use an `ArrayDeque`, preallocated to the right size? Actually, `ArrayDeque` implements both stack (DFS) and queue (BFS) APIs, so if you want to use an array, use the well-tested Java class.

Comment: Thats alright, the thing I am thinking is not using a queue structure at all. @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Let's think for a moment why BFS requires a queue, and DFS requires a stack. Basically, for a particular graph, for any node the algorithm may traverse to, said node of the graph may have multiple adjacent nodes that are yet to be visited. After all, this property is one of the most important ones that set graphs apart from lists: a node may have multiple or no connections. In fact, if the graph your algorithm is to work on is not something quite specific, it is entirely possible that at any node, you may have **O(N)** nodes as adjacent nodes to be visited, N being the number of nodes in that graph.

Now, as you have **O(N)** nodes as next destinations, and not **O(1)**, a single (or a *few* node variable(s) can not be considered as sufficient to store your next destinations.

This core need of storing multiple next destination is in what the usage of queue is rooted. You may refrain from using a queue by keeping the list of future destinations in an array, or in a file as you did. But what you do with that array or the file is basically implementing the functionality of queue: a data collection allowing **O(1)** insertion&deletion as well as **O(1)** access to the *front* element.

I am not claiming that this practice would be entirely useless. For instance, one such need for a custom queue implementation may come from having a limited memory or disk space to store the elements. It would possibly be less time-efficient, as one would have to consider the mostly constant factor of file access&modifications or other bookkeeping stuff done to maintain a fixed-size queue. Still, there may be legitimate uses of such custom queue implementations.

However, my main take on these custom implementations is that, even if you store it somewhere else or keep the size fixed, you still are using a queue, and you will have to keep using some form of a queue as long as the definition of the adjacency relationship in graph data structure, on which BFS works, is not redefined in a revolutionary way that leads to having only **O(1)** next destinations at a node. Currently, the only type of graph I think a BFS without a queue could work on without a queue is a linked list, and only if it starts from the beginning of the list.